# How to write to stdin with rjava's jri

Tags: java, r, rjava, jri

I am looking for a way to pipe a file to an R script using jri. I don't want to read the file in from the R script but rather pipe it directly into stdin with jri. Is there a way that I can get a file handle in jri that is connected to stdin and write to it. I have been looking at the code and it does not appear to be accessible.

http://rforge.net/JRI/

Thanks in advance,
Chris

Comment: I'm also looking to use this solution over using `source`, if you got it, i'll be happy to hear it, ill also try to figure it by myself. One thing that i found, that might be helpful,  is that the `eval` method can get multiple R lines, if you separate them with `;`

Comment: I ended up going another route, I created my own jni library that uses protocol buffers to assign my own REXP objects into and out of the R workspace. I am looking to open source it if you are interested. It is dramatically simpler than JRI but is only for osx and linux, no windows support in the near future. It may take me a week or so to get it ready for github but I will update this thread with an answer then.

Comment: I'd love to use it, thigh I'm using only windows